# Huawei UML397 U.S. Cellular 4G LTE Broadband USB Modem?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb, usb-modem, mobile-broadband

I am using Zorin OS 6 LTS, which I believe is technically Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Anyway, I was using an older 3G Modem from U.S. Cellular, and it worked perfectly with an easy setup (following [this guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Set-up-Mobile-Broadband-in-Ubuntu)) but now they wanted me to upgrade to the Huawei UML397 4G LTE USB Broadband Modem.

I was okay with this, since 4G LTE should be faster (what is the difference between 4G and 4G LTE anyway?) I expected a setup as easy as the last, and it showed up under the list of available adapters.

But I got to the step where I select my provider (U.S. Cellular), and it wasn't listed! I tried to enter it in, but then it asked for more information that it didn't with the last adapter! It asked me for an APN, and when I asked U.S. Cellular for it, they asked "what's an APN?". Is this a generic number, or one specific to my account/adapter? I couldn't find any info on my APN number online, except for ones for phones.

What should I do?

I also tested this on my regular Ubuntu 12.04 LTS computer, and got the same result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some experimenting and research, but I finally found the working settings.

1. Plug in your U. S. Cellular Huawei UML397 4G LTE USB Modem adapter.
2. Go to the networking applet in the menu bar and click "edit connections".
3. Go to the "Mobile Broadband" tab and click "Add".
4. Select your country.
5. U. S. Cellular won't be on the provider list, so enter "USCC" without quotes into the "My provider is not listed and I would like to enter it in manually" box; click "Next".
6. Do not select a plan (there won't be anything to select besides the default). Then, for the APN (**A**ccess **P**oint **N**ame) type in "usccinternet" without quotes, and then click "Next" or "Finish".
7. After the initial guided setup box has disappeared, highlight the "USCC Connection 1" as it will probably be named, and click "Edit".

**From here on, Each step is a how the settings should be on each tab.**

**If it is not mentioned, it should remain unchecked, blank, or with its default**

1. "Connect Automatically": Checked; "Method": "Automatic(PPP)".
2. "Name": "*99#"; APN: "usccinternet"; Type: "Any".
3. "Available to all users": Checked; "Allowed Methods": (you have to click the button under or next to it in order to change it) "PAP, CHAP".

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Better to contact the service provider

Try with selecting a similar service (providing same Modems and service Packages) in your county.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I can't really get any help with Linux for U.S. Cellular.